# what wrong the $(wildcard )?

Tags: makefile, wildcard

I wrote a makefile in an empty directory like this:

```
file_src=$(wildcard *.c)
display_file:
    @touch o.c&&echo $(file_src)
```

Then I ran make, but nothing was printed. Why is there no "o.c" printed?

Comment: Instead of `echo $(file_src)` you could `ls *.c`, but maybe you have bigger plans for the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have the order of operations wrong.

You are expecting make to expand `$(file_src)` (and thus the `$(wildcard)` call) **after** it runs the `touch` but that's not what happens.

Make expands `$(file_src)` (and the `$(wildcard)` call) **before** executing any of the recipe contents.

You can see this here:

```
$ cat Makefile
$(info echo Manual shell check)$(shell ls *.created)

file_src=$(shell touch make.created)

all:
        echo First recipe line; ls *.created
        echo $(file_src)
        touch recipe.created
        echo Final recipe line; ls *.created
$ ls
Makefile
$ make
echo Manual shell check
ls: *.created: No such file or directory
echo First recipe line; ls *.created
First recipe line
make.created
echo

touch recipe.created
echo Final recipe line; ls *.created
Final recipe line
make.created  recipe.created
```

Comment: thanks a lot.Does make expand all function brefore generating any target?

Comment: I see .$(file_src) is a make file variable ($(wildcard) is a makefile function ),So when $(file_src) appearing in the recipe which will be executing  ,$(file_src) (means variable and funtion )must be expand first,and then executing in shell.it's right？

Comment: [How `make` Reads a Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles) is a useful section of the manual in terms of how/when variables/etc. are expanded. In terms of recipes though the *entire* recipe is variable/etc. expanded *before* any of the recipe executes.